# Does GitHub CI support push options?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

GitLab has a whole page of documentation on the git push options that it supports,

```
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html
```

Does GitHub support any push options? I would like to specify that I want to open a pull request with a push to a branch and where that pull request should target. I would also like to have something like `ci.skip` so I can instruct CI not to run when I push up to a branch.

Basically, I want a method of not writing into the GitHub API to do what I can otherwise do on the web interface.

Comment: I opened a discussion on Github Actions, https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/113388

Comment: Can you also include why you need a "push options" feature in GitHub in your question??

Comment: @Ajay I will do that but I want to be clear this question isn't about what I'm trying to do, I want to know whether or not it supports push options.

Comment: The answer to your question is one Google search away. The simple answer is "No" because GitHub is not as focused or feature-rich as GitLabs regarding CI/CD and automation. So if you mention your purpose, we can find a workaround for the same in the GitHub.

Comment: @Ajay when you say the answer is a google search away, do you mean there is a Github document specifying that it does not support push options? Because I didn't see it. This is self-answered. I was intending to give back a simple answer to this question so others don't have through docs to conclude the same thing.